# Is a web domain sufficient to create email address?

Tags: email

I see a lot of posts regarding this topic however a lot of them do indirect advertising for web hosters. I struggle to understand if it is possible to create email address for free once I buy my domain name ?

My aim is to redirect them directly to my gmail account.

Thank you for your explanations.

Comment: No, the domain name registration is not enough.  You need to set a DNS record (MX) to tell other servers where your email should go.  Even then, once you tell them where it should go, the MX (assuming is pointing to Gmail) will not handle your email - Gmail needs to know that it's supposed to in charge of those emails - they can do it for you, for a fee

Comment: Yup, just set up an MX record pointing to your mail server.